# How to add date parameter and time now to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, datetime-format

I have a string date parameter as `04/14/2018`, and I want to add parameter with this date and time now to field datetime in Entity Framework. As sample

```
string value_date = '04/14/2018' ;   
add.Order_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(value_date);  
db.Products(add);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It's working, the data in database save as `2018-04-14 00:00:00` (the column `Order_Date` in database with type `smalldatetime`). If to get date and time now, easy to do this with `DateTime.Now` (it'll get value date and time as `2018-04-13 09:15:00`). So, I want to get date parameter with time now, as sample `2018-04-14 09:15:00`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get `TimeOfDay` and add to your date.

```
add.Order_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(value_date).Date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply construct a new DateTime object using the order date and the current time.

```
  var orderDate = Convert.ToDateTime("04/14/2018");

  var accurateDate = new DateTime(
    orderDate.Year, 
    orderDate.Month, 
    orderDate.Day, 
    DateTime.Now.Hour, 
    DateTime.Now.Minute, 
    DateTime.Now.Second);
```